# Dynamically load and execute the function code and render the template from database/Django

Tags: django, django-database

My task is to create a platform where teachers will insert questions with auto generate data in the form of code from various topics. The only idea I can come up with is to create a form with 2 fields where teacher will add function(logic) and html template, then save these codes as strings in database. When rendering the exercise for students, will dynamically load and execute the function code and render the template using the provided data. I know this can cause an app crash and it violence the security, but I’ll deal with that later.
I'm using Django. I created functions to add exercise for teachers. Unfortunately, after adding the exercise, I only see the text from the teacher template without the generated date. When the teacher adds the html template, he is asked to enter =“{{ exercise.url }}”> in the action. I generates a url for each exercise added by the teacher. Below is an example of functions and html that a teacher could add. I don’t know if what I’m doing is possible and if i can send view logic and template code to the database and dynamically load and execute?

Sorry for such a long post.

Here are my functions:

```
def add_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExerciseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            chapter_name1 = form.cleaned_data['chapter_name1']
            exercise_name1 = form.cleaned_data['exercise_name1']
            function_code = form.cleaned_data['function_code']
            template_code = form.cleaned_data['template_code']

            # Generate a unique URL for the exercise
            url = get_random_string(length=10)

            # Save the function code, template code, and URL as strings in the database
            exercise = Exercise(
                chapter_name1=chapter_name1,
                exercise_name1=exercise_name1,
                function_code=function_code,
                template_code=template_code
            )
            exercise.save()

            # Associate the generated URL with the exercise
            exercise.url = url
            exercise.save()

            # Redirect to the detail view of the created exercise
            return redirect('teacher:detail', url=exercise.url)
    else:
        form = ExerciseForm()

    return render(request, 'teacher/add_question.html', {'form': form})

def detail(request, url):
    exercise = get_object_or_404(Exercise, url=url)

    # Get the function code and template code as strings from the exercise model
    function_code = exercise.function_code
    template_code = exercise.template_code

    # Create a context dictionary to hold the data for rendering the template
    context = {
        'exercise': exercise,
        'question': exercise,  # Pass the exercise object as 'question' to the template
    }
    try:
        # Dynamically load and execute the function code
        exec(function_code, globals(), context)
        print("Function code executed successfully.")  # Debug print
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        # Handle the exception or return an error response


    # Render the template using the provided data
    template_engine = engines['django']
    template = template_engine.from_string(template_code)
    rendered_template = template.render(context, request)

    return render(request, 'teacher/detail.html', {'exercise': exercise, 'rendered_template': rendered_template})
```

add_question.html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'teacher:add_question' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Save Exercise</button>
</form>
```

detail.html:

```
    <h2>Exercise Details</h2>
<p>Chapter: {{ exercise.chapter_name1 }}</p>
<p>Exercise: {{ exercise.exercise_name1 }}</p>
<h3>Rendered Template:</h3>
{{ rendered_template|safe }}
```

example of teacher html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grouped Frequency Distribution</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Grouped Frequency Distribution</h1>

    <h2>These data represent the record high temperatures in degrees Fahrenheit (°F) for each of
        the 50 states. Construct a grouped frequency distribution for the data, using 7 classes.</h2>

    <h2>Data:</h2>
    <table>
        {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
                {% for value in row %}
                    <td>{{ value }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <h2>Enter the frequency:</h2>
    <form method="POST" action= "{{ exercise.url }}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for lower_limit, upper_limit, _ in frequency_distribution %}
            <label for="input_{{ forloop.counter }}">Class limits {{ lower_limit }} - {{ upper_limit }}:</label>
            <input type="number" id="input_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="input_{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% if is_correct is not None %}
        {% if is_correct %}
            <h2>Congratulations! Your results are correct.</h2>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Sorry, your results are incorrect. Please try again.</h2>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

example of teacher function:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from django.shortcuts import render

def calculate_frequency(request):
    # Generate random data
    data = [random.randint(100, 134) for _ in range(50)]
    num_rows = 5
    num_columns = 10
    data_table = [data[i:i + num_columns] for i in range(0, len(data), num_columns)]

    # Step 1: Determine the classes
    H = max(data)  # Highest value
    L = min(data)  # Lowest value
    R = H - L  # Range
    num_classes = 7
    class_width = R / num_classes


    # Step 2: Calculate the class boundaries
    lower_class_limit = L
    class_boundaries = [lower_class_limit + i * class_width for i in range(num_classes + 1)]
    upper_class_limit = class_boundaries[1:]

    # Step 3: Tally the data
    tally = [0] * num_classes
    for value in data:
        for i, upper_limit in enumerate(upper_class_limit):
            if value <= upper_limit:
                tally[i] += 1
                break

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_tally = []
        for i in range(num_classes):
            user_input = int(request.POST.get(f'input_{i+1}'))
            user_tally.append(user_input)

        # Compare user's results with the correct results
        correct_tally = tally
        correct = np.array(correct_tally)
        user = np.array(user_tally)

        # Check if the user's results match the correct results
        is_correct = np.array_equal(correct, user)
    else:
        is_correct = None

    # Step 4: Generate the grouped frequency distribution
    frequency_distribution = []
    for i in range(num_classes):
        lower_limit = int(class_boundaries[i])  # Convert lower limit to integer
        upper_limit = int(class_boundaries[i + 1])  # Convert upper limit to integer
        tally_value = tally[i]
        frequency_distribution.append((lower_limit, upper_limit, tally_value))

    context = {
        'data': data_table,
        'frequency_distribution': frequency_distribution,
        'is_correct': is_correct,
    }
    return render(request, 'instructor/frequency_distribution.html', context)
```

The website will not have any administrator therefore teachers need to send their code via form. I think, they need to send 2 files. One with code for function and one with html template. The problem is with url. In teacher html there is POST method with the action attribute set to {{ exercise.url }}. The {{ exercise.url }} is a placeholder that will be replaced with the URL associated with the current exercise. Detail function generate url for every question. I think here is the problem.